# Is the Laplace Transform of the convolution power the product of the Laplace Transformed convolution?

Tags: statistics, laplace-transform

In statistics, the definition of $F^k$ is the k-fold convolution of $F$ with itself, where $F$ is some common distribution. I am wondering if the following holds, if:

$$ 
L_{F^{k}(x)} = \left(L_{F(x)}\right)^k
$$

That is, the Laplace transform of the k-fold convolution is just the Laplace transform of the common distribution multiplied $k$ times. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: yes

Long answer: For any 2 functions $f(t)$ and $g(t)$, the Laplace tranform of the convolution is the product of Laplace transforms
$$\mathcal{L} \{ f(t) * g(t) \} = \mathcal{L}\{f(t)\} \mathcal{L}\{g(t)\}$$

It makes sense that this would hold no matter how many times we do the convolution

Comment: If these two functions are random variables, would that change anything?

Comment: I don't think it would. A variable is a variable